# C++ ASM get address of MOV

Tags: c++, assembly

I have the following line in ASM

```
_:004F73BB C6 83 54 41 03 00 01     mov  byte ptr [ebx+34154h], 1
```

In c++ i need to return the value of 34154h as an address ( 0x34154 )

Im hoping this can be done like so:

```
void getADR(BYTE *ptr1){//something like this?
     __asm{//i don't know how to call this at 004F73BB
          mov [ptr1], ebx
          mov  byte ptr [ebx+34154h], 1
     }
     // return ((BYTE)0x004F73BB - ptr1)
}
```

_____MY Logger____
This is my address logger that gets the ASM line 0x004F73BB
The playerpointer and server pointers are both easy to get because the byte patters point to a MOV and MOV returns the pointer of itself.

```
DWORD FindPattern(DWORD dwAddress, DWORD dwLen, BYTE *bMask, char * szMask)
{
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwLen; i++)
    if (Match((BYTE*)(dwAddress + i), bMask, szMask))
        return (DWORD)(dwAddress + i);

    return 0;
}
void SearchPatterns(void)
{
    while (true){

        add_log("ADR_PlayerPointer", "\xA4\xA2\xAE\x00", "xxx?", "A4 A2 AE 00, xxx?");
        add_log("ADR_ServerPointer", "\x48\x92\xAE\x00", "xxx?", "A1 48 92 AE 00, xxx?");
        add_log("OFS_5thSlot", "\x75\x09\xC6\x83\x54\x41\x03\x00\x01", "xxxxxxx?x", "75 09 C6 83 54 41 03 00 01, xxxxxxx?x");

        ExitProcess(0);
    }
}



BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HMODULE hDll, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    //DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hDll);
    if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        logging(hDll);
        CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)SearchPatterns, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

If you need more information leave a comment.

Comment: It sounds like you want to intelligently *disassemble* some bytes of machine code? Better look into using a disassembly library, e.g. [Capstone](http://www.capstone-engine.org/).

Comment: I am writing an address logger for a game. i don't need a library.

Comment: Well I have no idea what you're asking then. What is your input? A string of text?

Comment: The input should be some form of integer.

Comment: It is still not clear what exactly you are trying to do. Are you trying to modify memory in the current process?

Comment: @john the 34154h is the address for the 5th slot, if i do *(DWORD*)(PLAYERPOINTER + 0x34154) = 1; then the 5th slot enables. Yes i am trying to modify game memory.

Answer (score 0):

With that just bit of information, simply load the bytes into an char array, read the values at index 2, 3, 4, 5, do some little endian/big endian math. Or make a int* and make it point to the index 2 in the array and read the value.

Or if you know the offset in the binary, read the exe file, then point your int* to that location and read the value.

Comment: i dont think thats what i am looking for